# how can i solve flutter firebase auth

Tags: flutter

i create class for authentication firebase in flutter last version, And it was working perfectly
But After updating the firebase auth package, some errors appeared. see image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1BMR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors appeared after updating the firebase auth package to the latest version In the old version, there are no errors. old firebase auth : firebase_auth: ^0.15.3 last firebase auth : firebase_auth

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your app is ignorging the package, make sure you made the correct import, maybe `flutter pub get` did not work porperly, try running it again and restarting your app.

Also `FirebaseUser` is deprecated, chage it to `User`

Comment: These errors appeared after updating the firebase auth package to the latest version
In the old version, there are no errors.
old firebase auth : firebase_auth: ^0.15.3
last firebase auth : firebase_auth: ^1.3.0 (Null safety)